# Using Twilio with existing phone handset

Tags: twilio, phone-number

I have a question and I need to know if this Twilio integration is possible.

My client needs to keep the same business phone number (as it is marketed and printed in all advertisement).

She has a landline phone handset which is connected to ATT&T with the business phone number, but we have a different number for tech support.

I want to be able to integrate Twilio so that it works like this:

1.Client calls studio phone number
2. Twilio receives the call and presents a (press 1 to speak with the front desk, press 2 to speak with tech support prompt)
3. They press 1 and the studio phone handset rings and the front desk rep is able to take the call.
3a. They press 2 and they are connected to our tech support number.

Please help. If you need any more clarification, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

It sounds like the best approach here is to port the business phone number into Twilio.  This would let Twilio answer the incoming phone calls and execute your IVR for the callers, which solves steps 1 and 2 in your workflow.

For step 3, if you port the business phone number to Twilio then you'll need to find some other way to make the landline phone in the business ring since it won't have a phone number any more.  There are a few ways to do this:

- You could get a new phone number from AT&T that rings her landline.
- You could go VoIP and build a Twilio Client application hosted either in web browser or a native iPhone or Android app.

With either of these options, from when the user selects option 1 in your IVR, you would just use the `<Dial>` verb to have Twilio make an outbound connection (either to the new landline number or to the Client instance name) and Twilio will bridge the incoming customers call with that outbound call.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response.
If I chose to do the second option, how would I go about doing this?
"You could go VoIP and build a Twilio Client application hosted either in web browser or a native iPhone or Android app."

**Also, how does building a web app ring into a landline phone?

Comment: If you went with Twilio client this would effectively replace their landline phone.  Instead you would build them a VoIP phone either using JavaScript in the browser or in a native iOS or Android app.  All the business needs then is an internet connection and a computer or device like a smart phone or tablet.  AS an example check out:  https://www.twilio.com/webrtc  This shows making an outbound call from a browser to a phone using Twilio Client.  Not sure if we have an inbound example online.